# Change hostname on => ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'backup'@'yuvahealth.stream' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I have an VPS and when trying to connect to an mysql server on an remote server, I catch the error:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'backup'@'yuvahealth.stream' (using password: YES)

The connection is finally successfull, but **I want to change 'yuvahealt.stream' value**

How can I change the 'yuvahealt.stream' to another different?

Note: I dont have installed mysql-server on local machine, only mysql-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host part of the MySQL user `yuvahealth.stream` is the name that the MySQL Server got from a DNS lookup.

The MySQL Server resolves the IP address into a hostname, using a system call to `gethostbyaddr`.

That host value is not controlled by MySQL. The host value came from DNS, based on the IP address that connected to the MySQL Server.

If you want MySQL to see a different "host" value, you'd need to modify DNS entry so that the IP address resolves to a different hostname.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 Is there any manner to change the DNS entry directly from my VPS server, or this is a task for my VPS support? The server is serverhub.com
Is something related about I am using cloudflare's dns?
I suppose I need to link a DNS record to my IP on serverhub.com, doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

`'yuvahealt.stream'` is the host name you are connecting from (see MySQL manual on [account names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html)). This means that you can only change it by connecting from another host or by using IP address to identify accounts, or by using the generic `'%'` host name.

You cannot freely set to whatever you would like. You can only freely change the `'backup'` part of the username.